# How can I use a .Net dll in vba on a users machine

Tags: .net, dll, installation

I can access the dll in question on my dev machine and have created a .Net setup project. On a VM I install the setup.exe and it installs .Net. After installing I can see all of the public members when I use it in Excel vba but when I run it I get either "429 can't create object" or "Automation error".

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Excel 2007. The version of Excel is the same on my dev machine as it is on the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup project wasn't properly referencing my dll.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got the registration correct, so the next question is what version of Visual Studio are you using and what version of Excel?  There were two hotfixes put out for VS2005/Excel 2003, one for the build machine (which I can't find...) and [one for the client workstation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1b0bfb35-c252-43cc-8a2a-6a64d6ac4670&displaylang=en).  If you're using these two together you may want to apply that patch to the client workstation.